# Add short product description to Widget products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, widget, product

it is possible to add short description to the products list in the woocommerce products wordpress widget?
How I do it?

I'm not a pro, be easy in your answers, please!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should need to override WooCommerce `content-widget-product.php` template via your active theme. Here is a documentation related: [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

So you will need to create a folder named woocommerce in your active child theme (or active theme), if not done yet, in which you will copy the file located in: 
`wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-widget-product.php`
to:
`wp-content/themes/your-child-theme/woocommerce/content-widget-product.php`

Once done you will add after the line `34` the following:

```
<div class="produc-excerpt"><?php echo $product->get_short_description(); ?></div>
```

This will add the product short description for each product in the Widget Products output list.

---

> In upcoming WooCommerce version 3.3, you will be able to replace that using a custom function hooked in dedicated `woocommerce_widget_product_item_end` action hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_product_item_end', 'add_excerpt_to_widget_products'￼, 10, 1 );
function add_excerpt_to_widget_products( $args ) {
    global $product;

    echo '<div class="produc-excerpt">Bla: '. $product->get_short_description(). '</div>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works only in WooCommerce version 3.3+.